# How can I use the Fresh & Clean theme for blogging?

Tags: themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Limited blog support Fresh & Clean theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/68058/limited-blog-support-fresh-clean-theme)

I'm using the [Fresh & Clean theme](http://www.wpexplorer.com/fresh-clean-wordpress-theme-by-wpexplorer) and I am wondering how to use this theme for blogging. The theme only shows a summary of a post, you can only show the full text by using excerpts which is a very cumbersome way to compose posts. Is there an another to post full text posts using this theme?

Comment: Closed? Why can't I ask a normal question at this forum? Thanks @Gary_Gale for your help.

Comment: Because this is not a forum, waanders, it's a Q&A site. If the Question is a duplicate, it gets closed. Reading the FAQ will improve your experience here. Cheers!

Comment: I read the FAQ already. Thanks for adding a link to the duplicate question. Besides, I added a new question because my first one was closed (people didn't like it) so I couldn't update is to point out my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't actually make sense to me; but I think what you're saying is *"the landing page for my blog only shows post excerpts, to show the full post I need to view a post   as a single page; how do I show the full content of my posts on the landing page?"*

If that is indeed the case, you'll need to either create a child theme based on the theme (preferable) or edit the theme's templates (less preferable but quicker if you're not happy with the concept of creating child themes).

Regardless of your approach, you'll need to modify the contents of `post-entry.php`, which is loaded by the call to `get_template_part ('post', 'entry')` in `index.php`. The theme's `post-entry.php` file as shipped looks like this ...

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="post">
<div class="postcontent">
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {  ?>
<div class="thumbnail-wrap">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php     the_post_thumbnail('post-image'); ?></a>
</div><!-- END thumbnail-wrap -->
<?php } ?>
<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">       <?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div><!-- END Post Content -->
</div><!-- END Post -->
<?php endwhile; ?>`
```

... modify this file to change the call to `the_excerpt()` to `the_content()` and it should look like this ...

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="post">
<div class="postcontent">
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {  ?>
<div class="thumbnail-wrap">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('post-image'); ?></a>
</div><!-- END thumbnail-wrap -->
<?php } ?>
<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php the_content(); ?>
</div><!-- END Post Content -->
</div><!-- END Post -->
```

If I've misread your question and this isn't what you meant, please edit your question to clarify.